# DoublyLinkedList node operation not working as expected, giving wrong node data for .prev function

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently in the process of writing the deleteAt() function for my DLList program, although for trying to delete a node in the middle of the stack the code is acting unpredictably and I have no idea why?

For a previously created list containing the numbers: 
    2 , 3 , 9 , 8 , 7 , 4

and an operation to delete the data at node position: 2(the number 9)

My code acts oddly and instead of simply removing the data at position 2, it removes the data at position 2 and 1, so the outcome is: 2,8,7,4

When using the diplayNode() function I figured out that the line of code     DLLNode p = posFind.prev; instead of giving me the data for node previous to posFind at that particular iteration, it always gives me the data as if 
    posFind == head.next, 
so therefore it always return the data for 'head'

And I have no idea why this is happening as when i used the displayNode() function in the nested if() statement it returns to me the correct data for posFind at that particular iteration??

Any idea on why this is happening?

Code:

```
while (i < count) {
    if (i == pos) {
        DLLNode tmp = posFind.next;
        posFind.next = current;
        current.prev = head;  
        current.next = tmp;
        tmp.prev = current;
    }
    posFind = posFind.next;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What's stranger still is n = posFind.next; is working as expected and returning the right data, this is incredibly confusing....

Comment: Tell me if these assumptions are correct: 1) `head` is the first node in the list (index 0). 2) `pos` is the index you want to remove (index 2 in your example). 3) `posFind` represents the node that will be removed. 4) The code you posted is the entirety of your remove method.

Comment: 1) Correct: Head is the first node in the list (index 0)

2) Correct: pos is the index that is to be removed

3) Correct: posFind in the if() statement represents the node that will be removed

4) No: this is only the code for the removal of a node in the middle of the stack

I'll add the full code in as an edit to the main piece now

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with your code. I can recommend an optimation, though. Currently, you iterate through your entire list even after you've removed the element you're looking for. Instead, try moving the pointer directly to the node you want to remove, then remove it. `for (int i=1; i==pos; i++) posFind = posFind.next;`

Comment: Thanks for that, but is there any reason you can see why I might be experiencing this problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong (assuming the `displayNode` method does nothing strange). I guess there is a problem with the list even before removing a node. I assume you can print the list correctly to the console? Then I would say it is a wrong backpointer. Try to print the from tail to head to rule that out.

Comment: apologies, yes I meant positions 1 and 2, not 2 and 3, I confused myself with count and pos

Comment: Post fixed. I reversed the displayNodeList() (tail to head) and its now returning 4,7,8,2 instead of ,4,7,8,9,3,2. So there must be some problem with the .prev function for the 1st and 2nd positions in the stack, that would explain my problem, but how would i fix this? displayNodeList returns correctly for head to tail

Comment: Please show us the code building the list. (add method and the calls to it).

Comment: I agree with flo. The problem isn't in the code you've shown us so far.

Comment: I'll post them in the main question now

Comment: I'm missing the testing method.

Comment: any luck figuring out the problem?

Comment: I think it may be a problem with my insertBefore() method, as when I changed theses test cases  `testDLL.insertBefore(2,7);` 
            `testDLL.insertBefore(3,4);`
           `'testDLL.insertBefore(2,9);` 
           `testDLL.insertBefore(3,8);` 
to 
`testDLL.insertBefore(2,7);` 
             `testDLL.insertBefore(3,4);` 
            `testDLL.insertBefore(4,9);` 
            `testDLL.insertBefore(5,8);`
it seems to work perfectly now?

Comment: No, you don't get to remove the evidence of your assignments from this site.

Comment: i originally began with only the single function, it was an error somehwere else in the code that was causing the problem, hence the various multiple edits, it was not my intention to supply the full code in the fist place, by editing it down im still showing where the problem lied, so it still helps others who are experiencing this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found Waldo!

The mistake is in `insertBefore`.
You've got

```
while (i < count) {
    if (i == pos) {
        DLLNode tmp = posFind.next;
        posFind.next = current;
        current.prev = head;  <----- here!!!
        current.next = tmp;
        tmp.prev = current;
    }
    posFind = posFind.next;
    i++;
}
```

But the marked line should be

```
current.prev = posFind;
```

Setting the backpointer to head messed up every not-end insert.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of little errors in the code. In principle a solution boils down to the following:

```
public void deleteAt(int pos) {
    if (0 > pos || pos >= count) {
        return false;
    }
    DLLNode node = nodeAt(pos);
    if (node.prev != null) {
        node.prev.next = node.next;
    } else {
        head = node.next;
    }
    if (node.next != null) {
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
    } else {
        tail = node.prev;
    }
    --count;
    return true;
}

private DLLNode nodeAt(int pos) {
    if (0 > pos || pos >= count) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    DLLNode node;
    if (pos <= count/2) {
        node = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
            node = node.next;
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
    return node;
}
```

---

***Class Invariants:***

As you took the effort making unit tests, I would like to mention the usage of pre- and post-conditions. And especially invariants must be held *before* and *after* any operation.

```
assert (head == null && tail == null && count == 0)
    || (head != null && tail != null && count > 0);

assert (node.prev == null && head == node)
    || (node.prev != null && node.prev.next == node);

assert (node.next == null && tail == node)
    || (node.next != null && node.next.prev == node);
```

Comment: implementing this seems to delete all elements of the stack?

Comment: I could have made an error, but my first guess would be that the data structure got corrupted. A dump of the phyiscal structure would be helpful for you. I added class invariants, which are even more strict than unit tests for a limited number of test-cases.